# Snake_case в camelCase

Tags: javascript

В строке необходимо найти все дефисы или нижние подчеркивания, убрать их и букву после них сделать большой:

```js
function toCamelCase(string) {
  return string.replace(/-|_/gi, (str, index, s) => {
    return s[index + 1].toUpperCase();
  });
}

console.log(toCamelCase("the-stealth-warrior"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо захватывать ещё и первую букву, иначе её `replace` не заменяет:

```js
function toCamelCase(string) {
  return string.replace(/(?:-|_)\w/gi, (str, index, s) => {
    return s[index + 1].toUpperCase();
  });
}

console.log(toCamelCase("the-stealth-warrior"));
```